# How to remove index.php from front end URL In magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I am working on magento-1.9.

How to remove index.php from my website's front end url?

Any one know so please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Go admin side : `System` -> `Configuration` -> `Web (Under General tab)` and open `Search Engines Optimization` and set `Yes` in field "`Use Web Server Rewrites`"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php from urls follow the below steps :

```
1) Log-in Magento Admin
2) Go to System -> Configuration -> Web.
3) from ‘Search Engine Optimisation’ tab “Use Web Server Rewrites” select 'YES'.
4) Make sure your “Secure” and “Unsecure” base urls should end with “/”.
5) now edit your .htaccess ( will be in magento root folder ) and pate the below code and save:


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

More detail posted [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error).