# How do I get Http_referer path without "http://localhost/index.php/"?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, http-request

I want to get the preview page url using:

```
Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer();
```

and it get's me something like:

```
http://localhost/index.php/customer/account/
```

**How do I get just : `customer/account/`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you use PHP native method `parse_url()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
var_dump(parse_url(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()));
```

It will give you the following result:

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["path"]=>
  string(28) "/index.php/customer/account/"
}
```

If you want to remove the index.php you can then do:

```
str_replace("/index.php","","/index.php/customer/account/");
```

However, if you want to remove index.php for every page (which is I reckon you should do) you should check this post: [How to remove index.php from front end URL In magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85960/in-magento-how-to-remove-index-php-in-url)

Comment: I know , but I want the path without  `index.php`.

Comment: @ana.coman93 see my update