# Removing index.php from product pages results in 404 error

Tags: overrides, url, seo

I have been trying to figure out how I can get rid of index.php before my product URLs. The home page is ok but when I click products it throws up 404. I have changed the config with seo url rewrites to yes. 
[www.robsteele.co.uk/clickdev](http://www.robsteele.co.uk/clickdev)

Comment: Hi Rob, welcome to Magento StackExchange. Check out these answers here, there are a lot of details what needs to be done/checked: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error/46966#46966

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to enable mod rewrite in apache, depending on your OS it might be different, but if you are on for example ubuntu it can be done with the command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Yeah have asked hosts. My phpinfo is here cant see mod rewrite on here. http://www.robsteele.co.uk/clickdev/phpinfo.php

Comment: Its not a PHP setting so not sure you can see it in your PHP config.