# How can i remove index.php from magento url?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have tried everything I found in the different post related to this.

I already review:

```
• The magento setting is correct.
• That the rewrite module is enabled.
• The rules and conditions in it .htaccess.
```

But magento keeps sending me the 404 error every time I try to navigate, only the home page works.

**This is the Magento Config**

```
Go to System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization

Use Web Server Rewrites: YES
And the Unsecure and Secure too.
```

**This is the configuration on my .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

---

Is there anything else I should do?

---

Comment: check this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove /index.php from the Magento URL gives 404 error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Work for me: **If somebody needs the answer**

**I put the configuration from the .htacces file on my vhost.conf on apache**

```
<Directory /var/www/magento/>
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the simple steps below

1) Change a Setting in the Admin section.

The first thing you need to do is to log in to your Magento admin panel (index.php/admin) to change a very simple setting which will let Magento know that you intend to use URL rewriting throughout your store rather than their ugly default URLs.

Login, and change the following setting:

Go to System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization

Use Web Server Rewrites: YES

That was easy, wasn’t it? Okay, now for the final step.

2) Use a .htaccess File to rewrite the URLs

The final step involves creating a .htaccess file in the Magento installation folder in order to compliment the settings you have changed within your admin settings earlier, and this will actually rewrite the URLs. Choose the applicable .htaccess version below.

If your Magento store is installed in root (public_html), use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If your Magento store is installed in a subfolder (public_html/shop), use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
```