# How to Remove index.php from Magento URL | show error 404

Tags: magento-1.9

we follow all steps for remove index.php in url
step like:

1. change admin panel config > general.. > web > seo or other = YES,
2. .htaccess file.

**`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`**

When we click any menu then it directly displays 404 page!

Comment: Hi, You can find your answer from following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998156/case-insensitive-urls-with-mod-rewrite and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156461/how-can-i-remove-index-php-from-magento-url?rq=1 . Apart from it first of all check mod_rewrite is enable on your server or not?