# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Can only access admin panel using htttp://domain.com/index.php/admin

Tags: admin-panel, index.php

I am struggling to find a solution to this problem the site in question http://vvspris.no can only grants access to the admin panel if i use "index.php" between the url and admin panel name i.e vvspris.no/index.php/vsadmin.

I have turned on pretty urls and cleared the cache, reindexed and compiled but no change. Tried multiple browsers with the same result.

The Error get when accessing WITHOUT index.php is:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /vsadmin was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hello, Please Check This :***

**[Remove /index.php from the Magento URL gives 404 error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/21033/59400) .**

Your all doubts and problem will be solved.

Thank you.

Comment: I read through the thread and made the required changes to the .htaccess file but still the same problem. My SEO freiendly rewrites are on.

Comment: Which server is yours APACHE or NGINX. 
.htaccess does not work on NGINX server . 
If your server is NGINX , then you proabably have to set up configuration file of NGINX. 
see this https://gist.github.com/Jonathonbyrd/7492621 to set configuration on NGINX server. @c2aFrederick

Comment: @Webwavers, we use Apache.