# Magento 1.9 admin panel routing issue

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

when I enter url http://magento.premierexports.co.uk/magento/admin 
that time magento admin panel not open.
Instead of this when I enter url http://magento.premierexports.co.uk/magento/index.php/admin
  that time admin panel is open.
please provide solution

Comment: Refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46966/2443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow following step :

Login, and change this setting Go to

> System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization
>
> Use Web Server Rewrites: YES

Then check .htaccess file exist or not in root , If not then include it from copying any default magento setup.
Put the following code in the created file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In case your Magento is installed in sub-folder, e.g. 'shop', you should use the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: given Code worked like charm

Comment: Your welcome :-)