# How can i remove index.php from Categories URL & Products URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-urls, index.php

In my base url not have index.php, but my all categories and products url  consists index.php. How can i remove this.

Note : Base url have not index.php

Comment: Please clear your cache and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled this option ?

Login to Admin and got to :

> System->Configurations->Web

and then in "**Search Engine Optimization Tab**" select **Yes**

Comment: Yes, already the option is yes.

Comment: then check if mode_rewrite enabled on your server and .htaccess ?

Comment: How can i enable mode_rewrite in both server and .htaccess?

Comment: check this post link to know how to enable mode_rewrite, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: after changes in .htaccess stil not working -> screen shot https://snag.gy/pMUD27.jpg

Comment: may i know possibilities of error.

Comment: which OS / hosting are you using ? there are only 2 ways to check and fix required : 1 ) enabling the option, 2 ) checking mod_rewrite thing and as per you both are correct, now tell me index.php is being added in all urls etc ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75483/discussion-between-zus-and-naveed).

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this path in your Magento,

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization

And set `Use Web Server Rewrites` to **YES**.

After doing this please refresh your cache and check it.

Comment: Yes, already the option is yes

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization` And set `Use Web Server Rewrites` to **YES**.
2. Take backup of previous both .htaccess files then again Upload .htaccess and .htaccesssample files into your server.
3. Clear your cache and do re-index management again.

Comment: Still not working, .htaccess changes -> https://snag.gy/pMUD27.jpg

Comment: may i know the possibilities of error.

Comment: @zus, As of i told, reupload .htaccess files both. then you will get the sucess

Answer (score 0):

**To remove index.php from URLs follow the below steps :**

```
Log-in Magento Admin.
Go to System -> Configuration -> Web.
From Search Engine Optimisation tab Use Web Server Rewrites select YES.
Make sure your Secure and Unsecure base urls should end with “/”.
```

Comment: may i know the possibilities of error.