# Sites are only loading if I add `index.php` to the URL

Tags: magento-1.8, database, index

I just copied the live database to my local environment. I changed the base_url to the new domain (virtual host).

My sites on my local environment are only loading if I add index.php to the URL. e.g. http://mysite.local/index.php

If I enter http://mysite.local/ then I get redirected to http://mysite-local/

I already reindexed all.

What is going on?

This is the .htaccess entry which is responsible for the rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>

        ############################################
        # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

        ############################################
        # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please follow : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Solved</s>. The old domain was still in chrome cache. I opened the developer console and disabled cache. Then I reloaded the site and BOOM. It works!

I hate Chromes aggressive cache...